# Define a linter rule for flutter and dart

Tags: flutter, dart, linter

As you know there are some pre-defined rules for linter, but I wonder how can I define a custom linter rule for flutter and dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write a plugin for the analysis server, but the docs caution:

> Note: The plugin support is not currently available for general use.

Just in case you want to ignore that, look at the analyzer docs at: https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer_plugin and the linter docs at:
https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/blob/master/doc/WritingLints.MD

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the [analyzer](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer) package to your dependencies and then make a `analysis_options.yaml` file in the root of your project. in there you can import other analyzer rules like [effective_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/effective_dart) or add the ones that you need from the [lint rule list](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/).

Here is an example for `analysis_options.yaml`:

```yaml
linter:
  rules:
    - camel_case_types
    - empty_constructor_bodies
```